# multiple insert with sequence fails in Postgres

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, liquibase

There is one insert query with multiple values (about 18k):

```
INSERT INTO ENTRIES (ID, USER_ID) 
VALUES (nextval('my_seq'), '233'),(nextval('my_seq'), '233');
```

Which is fired from liquibase changeset in java application:

```
JdbcConnection connection = (JdbcConnection) database.getConnection();

        ResultSet resultSet = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT ID FROM USERS").executeQuery();

        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Long userId = resultSet.getLong(1);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                values.add("(nextval('my_seq'), '" + userId + "')");
            }
        }

        String sql = "INSERT INTO ENTRIES (ID, USER_ID) VALUES " + join(values, ",") + ";";

        connection.createStatement().execute(sql);
```

When it is executed against h2 database, everything is fine, but when I am running that against postgres the following exception is being thrown:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "entries_pkey"
```

Like id from sequance is being reused.

When running sql in pgAdmin everything is ok, but from application it fails on the first insert.

My first thought is that maybe sql should be executed somehow differently.

Any thoughts on this?

Here is table description:

```
  CREATE TABLE entries
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  user_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT entries_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_e3udjwux3ly7lu31huish0f82 FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE entries
  OWNER TO app;
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of the entries table?

Comment: Why don't you use a default value for the ID-field? Let the database handle the increments and you're fine, you don't have to mention this field in your INSERT statements anymore.

Comment: @FrankHeikens when using nextval in defaults it is the same error.

Comment: What is the primary key on the entries table? Is it possible to simply use `INSERT INTO entries (id, user_id) ( SELECT nextval('my_seq'), id FROM users)`?

Comment: When you get the same error, your sequence isn't up to date: The value generated by this sequence is already used. Check the max(id) in your table and the current value of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your sequence counter needs to be reset (perhaps you had manually entered numbers in your table instead of using nextval so counter was not incremented) and its giving out numbers you already have in your table.  Trying reseting it with something like

```
ALTER SEQUENCE my_seq RESTART 100000;
```

Where 100000 is a number greater than:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM entries;
```

Comment: the problem is that it is happening on empty table, data is inserted only with that insert query. so it is impossible.

Comment: sandris,  sorry had missed reading that part. Your code for jdbc of what little I remember of jdbc looks fine (except user_id should not be quoted if an integer).  Though that wouldn't cause your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, if your dbms can do something automatically, you shouldn't try to do it yourself.

```
CREATE TABLE entries
(
  -- bigserial provides automatic sequence numbers under
  -- dbms control.
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  user_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT entries_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_e3udjwux3ly7lu31huish0f82 FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

Insert into this table without referring to "id" at all.

```
INSERT INTO ENTRIES (USER_ID) 
VALUES ('233'),('233');
```

Or use the "default" value.

```
INSERT INTO ENTRIES (ID, USER_ID) 
VALUES (default, '233'),(default, '233');
```

In this context *default* is not a string. (No quotation marks.)

Answer (score 0):

Code was correct, the problem was size of the sequence - it was too small for 18k insert.